# What is the purpose/effect of providing the 'generic' argument to `NextMethod()`?

Tags: r, generics, methods, r-s3

I am trying to understand what the purpose of the `generic` argument of `NextMethod()` is.

#### Example

```
# example data
x <- as.Date(c("2022-01-01", "2023-01-01", "1900-01-01", "2024-01-01")) 

# gives cumulative maximum as expected
cummax.Date <- function(x, ...) .Date(NextMethod(), cl = oldClass(x))
cummax(x)
#> [1] "2022-01-01" "2023-01-01" "2023-01-01" "2024-01-01"

# gives cumulative minimum as expected
cummin.Date <- function(x, ...) .Date(NextMethod(), cl = oldClass(x))
cummin(x)
#> [1] "2022-01-01" "2022-01-01" "1900-01-01" "1900-01-01"
```

#### Best Practice

[Quite often](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/3e590f84194b8ce975ad9ee84ef3330a74c0c63d/R/duplicated.R#L2), the generic is called explicitely.

```
cummin.Date <- function(x, ...) .Date(NextMethod(generic = "cummin"), cl = oldClass(x))
cummin(x)
#> [1] "2022-01-01" "2022-01-01" "1900-01-01" "1900-01-01"
```

#### Bad Practice - no Difference

However, explicitly calling the generic does not impact the result whatsoever, no matter if it exists or not.

```
# still returns the cumulative minimum
cummin.Date <- function(x, ...) .Date(NextMethod(generic = "cummax"), cl = oldClass(x))
cummin(x)
#> [1] "2022-01-01" "2022-01-01" "1900-01-01" "1900-01-01"

# still returns the cumulative minimum
cummin.Date <- function(x, ...) .Date(NextMethod(generic = "foobar"), cl = oldClass(x))
cummin(x)
#> [1] "2022-01-01" "2022-01-01" "1900-01-01" "1900-01-01"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NextMethod` uses argument `generic` only if it does not find the symbol `.Generic` in the calling environment of the method.  That happens only in atypical usage:

```r
> .S3method("mean", "a", function(x, ...) { rm(.Generic); NextMethod() })
> mean(structure(1:6, class = "a"))
Error in NextMethod() : generic function not specified
> .S3method("mean", "b", function(x, ...) { rm(.Generic); NextMethod("diff") })
> mean(structure(1:6, class = "b"))
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
attr(,"class")
[1] "b"
> .S3method("mean", "c", function(x, ...) { .Generic <- "diff"; NextMethod() })
> mean(structure(1:6, class = "c"))
[1] 1 1 1 1 1
attr(,"class")
[1] "c"
```

It is undocumented (I think), but visible in the [sources](https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/blob/41bc842cb35cfc5ca644ada0e377a0cd4fba5e79/src/main/objects.c#L704-L949) of the internal `do_nextmethod`, which uses `readS3VarsFromFrame` (defined [elsewhere](https://github.com/r-devel/r-svn/blob/41bc842cb35cfc5ca644ada0e377a0cd4fba5e79/src/main/envir.c#L1112-L1164)) to locate `.Generic`.

I don't think that anyone would recommend assigning to `.Generic`, removing `.Generic`, or otherwise calling `NextMethod` in a context where `.Generic` is not there.  Indeed, I think that the advice in `help("NextMethod")` about `.Class` applies here:

> Note that `.Class` is set when the generic is called, and is unchanged if the class of the dispatching argument is changed in a method.  It is possible to change the method that `NextMethod` would dispatch by manipulating `.Class`, but 'this is not recommended unless you understand the inheritance mechanism thoroughly' (Chambers & Hastie, 1992, p. 469).